# Thead is not working when printing, if it is oversize

Tags: html, css, printing

I want to make a webpage for printing(using window.print()), with a header and footer in every page. However, I found a weird thing about tag thead.

If there is too many rows in tag thead, it will properly show in the first page, but disappear in the second page.

As you can see in the example, I put 8 rows in thead, it works. Both thead and tfoot appear in every pages; but if I add 9th row in thead, the whole header will disappear in second page.

Please help, I've tried many ways, none of them work, and I can't find others having the similar problem. 
Thank you.

```css
@media print 
  {
   @page
   {
    size: landscape; /* $$ doesn't work on IE, ask user change to landscape manually */
   }  
  }
  thead { display: table-header-group; }
 tfoot { display: table-footer-group; }
 
 table 
 {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%; 
 }
 
 table, th, td 
 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
 }
 
 td
 {
  height: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<html><head>

 
 </head>
 

  <body>

            <table id="print_table">
             
             <thead>
              <tr>
               <th>TEST thead 1</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
               <th>TEST thead 2</th>
              </tr>
     <tr>
               <th>TEST thead 3</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
               <th>TEST thead 4</th>
              </tr>
     <tr>
               <th>TEST thead 5</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
               <th>TEST thead 6</th>
              </tr>
     <tr>
               <th>TEST thead 7</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
               <th>TEST thead 8</th>
              </tr>
     

             </thead>
    <tfoot>
 <tr>
  <th>TEST tfoot</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>TEST tfoot</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>TEST tfoot</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>TEST tfoot</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>TEST tfoot</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>TEST tfoot</th>
 </tr>
 </tfoot>
    <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td>00001</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>00002</td> 
</tr><tr>
 <td>00003</td> 
</tr><tr>
 <td>00004</td> 
</tr><tr>
 <td>00005</td> 
</tr><tr>
 <td>00006</td>
</tr><tr>
 <td>00007</td>
</tr><tr>
 <td>00008</td>
</tr><tr>
 <td>00009</td>
</tr><tr>
 <td>00010</td>
</tr><tr>
 <td>00011</td>
</tr><tr>
 <td>00012</td>
</tr><tr>
 <td>00013</td>
</tr><tr>
 <td>00014</td>
</tr><tr>
 <td>00015</td>
</tr><tr>
 <td>00016</td>
</tr><tr>
 <td>00017</td>
</tr><tr>
 <td>00018</td>
</tr><tr>
 <td>00019</td>
</tr><tr>
 <td>00020</td>
</tr><tr>
 <td>00021</td>
</tr>
 </tbody>
 
</table>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Did you check the location of your stylesheet?

Comment: Yes, I did. Seems like it doesn't really matter in such a simple table.